# Laravel User Access issue in Creating Database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I would need my Laravel app to create a database which is defined by the user. Here are my settings and codes:

```
'mysql_only_connect'  => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port'      => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database'  => null,
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', '')            
        ],
```

---

```
DB::connection('mysql_only_connect')->statement("CREATE DATABASE db_name DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8;");
```

And I'm having a user access denied issue when creating a database but I've been using the same DB user in accessing other databases. I highly suspect it has something to do with the user but I'm not sure how to correctly set a user access account for this scenario.

Notes:

1. I have no issue running locally but on the server.
2. I have no issue when simply creating tables under a database already created via WHM/cPanel.

I would appreciate any help and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I just have to grant a "create" privilege to the mysql user, thanks to [this](https://www.lowendtalk.com/discussion/34667/how-to-grant-a-user-to-create-database-phpmyadmin) discussion.

```
# mysql -u root -psomepass 
mysql> grant create on *.* to testguy@localhost;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> flush privileges;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> Bye

# mysql -u testguy -psomepass

mysql> create database frack;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.11 sec)
```